# Split comma seperated value and match with checkbox value and check that checkbox along with its parent checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have comma seperated value store in my variable and i will use this comma seperated value and match with my checkbox value and with those match checkbox value i will check that checkbox along with it parent checkbox.

I want to do this action on `document.ready`.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var id="1,2"; //here id can contain value either 1,2 or 3,4
     //Now i want to split id variable value by comma and want to find all checkbox in Checkboxprocess div only and if any checkbox value match with checkbox then i want to
     //check that checkbox along with its parent checkbox.
     //For Eg if Id contains 1,2 then i want to check checkbox chkchild1 and chkchild2 and its parent chkParent1
   });
```

```html
<div id="Checkboxprocess">
<div id="section1">
<input type="checkbox" id="chkParent1" runat="server" value="Check All" />
---------Parent of section 1----
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="abc" runat="server" value="1" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="pqr" runat="server" value="2" />
    </li>                                
</div>
<br>
<br>

<div id="section2">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkParent2" runat="server" value="Check All" />
  ---------Parent of section 2----
   
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="lmn" runat="server" value="3" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="xyz" runat="server" value="4" />
    </li>                                
</div>
</div>
```

This is my fiddle link:[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n08645j1/9/)

Comment: Sorry posted a wrong fiddle link.Updated

Comment: `$('#chkchild' + id.split(',').join(', #chkchild')).prop('checked', true);` [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/6vawhbdp/)

Comment: downvoter please give me your reason for downvoting

Comment: I did not downvote you but there's actually no question in your "question".  Consider adding one.

Comment: @billynoah:Now see my updated question

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a language issue but there is still no question present here.  Please post a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var id = "1,2"; //here id can contain value either 1,2 or 3,4 //Now i want to split id variable value by comma and want to find all checkbox in Checkboxprocess div only and if any checkbox value match with checkbox then i want to //check that checkbox along with its parent checkbox. //For Eg if Id contains 1,2 then i want to check checkbox chkchild1 and chkchild2 and its parent chkParent1

/*Get All the checkbox. This includes parent checkboxes too*/
var allCheckboxes = $('#Checkboxprocess input:checked');

/*loop through checkboxes*/
$.each(allCheckboxes, function () {
    /*get the value of check box. Please note that this will also include the value of parent checkbox too but as the 'id' variable will only contain values of child checkboxes, the $.inArray(checkBoxVal,id) values always return '-1' in case of parent checkbox value. */
    /*Getting the value of each checkbox and $.inArray(checkBoxVal,id)
  checks if checkbox value present in id variable or not */
    var checkBoxVal = $(this).val();
    if ($.inArray(checkBoxVal, id) > -1) {
        /*Get parent checkbox*/
        var parentChechBox = $(this).closest('div').find(':checkbox:first');
        $(parentChechBox).prop('checked', 'checked');
    }
});});
```

Comment: i have doubt on this line:#Checkboxprocess input:checked.Why it is checked?

Comment: @Learning you want to check the parent checkbox if any of the child checkboxes are checked.. so get all 'checked' checkbox and if any of the child boxes are checked this will make subsequent parent checked. You can further apply filters on the basis of id name. this is generic one and will solves your problem i feel.

Comment: can you tell me where you are checking child checkbox based on id match with checkbox value?

Comment: @Learning check my code with comments added.

Comment: Format your code.its very improper

Comment: Ahh finally managed to paste properly..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99661/discussion-between-learning-and-abhishek).